# Does this HDTune result indicate a bad/damaged HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata, defective-hardware

Recently, my laptop started slowing down a lot more than usual, where it took more than 5 minutes to load Visual Studio (Before, it only took at max 30 seconds).

so I ran an HDTune Benchmark:

[image]

This is a 750 Gig 5400RPM SATA Laptop Harddrive.

My impression was, for non-ssd drives, the benchmark result should look like a curve, starting from the top.

However, this result seems very sproadic, minimum being 0.3, maximum 97 and average 33.

Does this mean I need to replace my HDD?

Comment: Maybe there are other programs or services accessing the hard drive, causing these performance hits?

Comment: I'd take a look at the health and surface scan tabs too

Comment: @Gene As far as I know, there weren't any other processes running.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No errors reported from Smart.